# Cucumber: how to switch sessions in Rails (multi-session)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I need to change session during one cucumber scenario.

For example

```
Given session name is "1st unauthenticated user"
And make some things
Given session name is "2st unauthenticated user"
And make some other things
```

I found a [solution](http://niczsoft.com/2010/03/cucumber-multi-session/), but it doesn't work with Rails 3, Cucumber and Capybara. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found great article that help to solve this problem: http://tristandunn.com/2010/10/21/multiple-sessions-cucumber-selenium.html